# How to correct Correlation problem in loadrunner

Tags: performance, loadrunner

I've generated following script in VUGEN (LR Community Edition) and getting the following error when replaying.

**Error**:

```
Action.c(36): Error -35061: No match found for the requested parameter 
"CorrelationParameter". Check whether the requested boundaries exist in the 
response data. Also, if the data you want to save exceeds 9999 bytes, use 
web_set_max_html_param_len to increase the parameter size   [MsgId: MERR-35061]
```

**Output:**

```
Action()
{
web_set_max_html_param_len("9999"); 
/*Correlation comment - Do not change!  Original value='x-AR3oHRoaXc9bX3qP2PLkxYiQg_q8TvLTRPK9Ope0D02-hgNuxiJq1lC3aRGYptDP8YxEv3k2JwXD5RJo2SXuf4vh41' Name ='__RequestVerificationToken_2' Type ='ResponseBased'*/
    web_reg_save_param_ex(
        "ParamName=__RequestVerificationToken_2",
        "LB=type=\"hidden\" value=\"",
        "RB=\" ",
        SEARCH_FILTERS,
        "Scope=Body",
        "IgnoreRedirections=No",
        "RequestUrl=*/scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/*",
        LAST);

    web_url("scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net", 
        "URL=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=", 
        "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        LAST);

/*Correlation comment - Do not change!  Original value='pjstSpLHCLNXxzjr5q58357xuyDChqEcqBHG489Ouzvoy1zw0uSq6hb60mZSUQWz44eIn4cJ/We4jZZiOysixJSOP641W5b5k3Ig+57gqIoVzmLp6vF52fhgUPOZbIXU542AOg==' Name ='CorrelationParameter' Type ='ResponseBased'*/
    web_reg_save_param_ex(
        "ParamName=CorrelationParameter",
        "LB=\"Url\":\"/signalr\",\"ConnectionToken\":\"",
        "RB=\",",
        SEARCH_FILTERS,
        "Scope=Body",
        "IgnoreRedirections=No",
        "RequestUrl=*/negotiate*",
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net_2",
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/",
        "Method=POST",
        "EncodeAtSign=YES",
        "TargetFrame=",
        "RecContentType=text/html",
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/",
        "Snapshot=t2.inf",
        "Mode=HTML",
        ITEMDATA,
        "Name=__RequestVerificationToken", "Value={__RequestVerificationToken_2}", ENDITEM,
        "Name=Email", "Value=alifar.hangill@gmail.com", ENDITEM,
        "Name=Password", "Value=password", ENDITEM,
        "Name=RememberMe", "Value=false", ENDITEM,
        LAST);

    web_convert_param("CorrelationParameter_URL2",
        "SourceString={CorrelationParameter}",
        "SourceEncoding=HTML",
        "TargetEncoding=URL",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("abort",
        "URL=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/signalr/abort?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken={CorrelationParameter_URL2}&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D",
        "Method=POST",
        "TargetFrame=",
        "Resource=0",
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/QuickWizard",
        "Snapshot=t3.inf",
        "Mode=HTML",
        "EncType=application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        LAST);

    web_url("Dashboard", 
        "URL=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/QuickWizard", 
        "Snapshot=t4.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("GetSalesCycle", 
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/Widgets/GetSalesCycle", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "Snapshot=t5.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=sort", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=group", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=filter", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("MandrillOpenWidget", 
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/Widgets/MandrillOpenWidget", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "Snapshot=t6.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=sort", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=group", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=filter", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("GAAreaChart", 
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/Widgets/GAAreaChart", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "Snapshot=t7.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=sort", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=group", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=filter", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("DocumentWidget", 
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/Widgets/DocumentWidget", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "Snapshot=t8.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=sort", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=group", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=filter", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("LeadSourceWidget", 
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/Widgets/LeadSourceWidget", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "Snapshot=t9.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=sort", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=group", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=filter", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("MandrillDeliveredWidget", 
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/Widgets/MandrillDeliveredWidget", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "Snapshot=t10.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=sort", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=group", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=filter", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("GetInvoicesStats", 
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/Widgets/GetInvoicesStats", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "Snapshot=t11.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=sort", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=group", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=filter", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("ResolvePendingIssueWidget", 
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/Widgets/ResolvePendingIssueWidget", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "Snapshot=t12.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
        "Name=sort", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=group", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        "Name=filter", "Value=", ENDITEM, 
        LAST);

    web_add_cookie(".ASPXAUTH=68AEAF321CD8294497F19F05B936960681A25C158A40E12EA6C41E57E13BF40F02DEB0F51EBC0A5A4A0B049A733027FBB952ECED967658503ED14B63FE2FFEA97380EBB708DF4E13DAF42D6F473A519F4EDF1F1A1887B110C3C294483CC452288949A0353124C88BEC877A4AA6BAA52102C09FA7; DOMAIN=scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net");

    web_custom_request("abort_2", 
        "URL=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/signalr/abort?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=EOS2PQ4lJ3ps%2B8i5qe4k680RORMBlFoR2ahxk12cStBZVx3ZvDlMHVAvCsJJ1ub62xUFvLsUgPBy25gYqo0dTFK6dTv4VTbhgdvoSX3%2BemDZ32qLTQx%2BUSXdoIl3oR5ZzGPCuQ%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard", 
        "Snapshot=t13.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "EncType=application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
        LAST);

    web_submit_data("LogOff",
        "Action=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/Account/LogOff",
        "Method=POST",
        "TargetFrame=",
        "RecContentType=text/html",
        "Referer=http://scoretestsrv.cloudapp.net/CRO/Dashboard",
        "Snapshot=t14.inf",
        "Mode=HTML",
        ITEMDATA,
        "Name=__RequestVerificationToken", "Value=mgKPnNE50ng7ibltWTO__OHsMHln0KfuJ4GuTVMbc0sLeh5k_xkM2Q-XS5jZGezVMjzwfObUnRaKZwymH5xxxNrcE34YSMj3WNFn5srD2zuh6avR0", ENDITEM,
        LAST);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correlation especially done for the Sessions and data which changes frequently for making secure connection and data transmission .. try to find those data and correlate them alone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the below are taken care of

- Check whether the left boundary and right boundary are correct, it should be same as that comes from response.
- Check whether you have placed the **web_reg_save_param_ex** above the first occurrence of the dynamic value in the response data.
- Whether the response of the previous requests are successful/ correct. If there is any of above response is failing it may fail the subsequent request also. In case of any failures check for any dynamic value from server that is not correlated and correlate it.

Only the dynamic value needs to be correlated, any user provided inputs can be parameterized. If any dynamic value is left unhandled, it will most probably fail during multiple users run/ multiple iterations run.

Without having the recording/replay logs it is hard to figure out why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Correlation especially done for the **Sessions** and data like *username* which changes frequently for making secure connection and data transmission .. try to find those data and correlate them alone.

if you correlate other values problem would occur while passing the input parameters.

Try to use the **Auto Correlation** option 
for selecting the Auto correlation follow these steps:
Recording Options--> Configuration--> Check Auto correlation options.